SettingActivty.java cannot attach the BottomNaviagtonView
Any Android guru here, please advise as i have recently learned Android. Just create a SettingActivity.java together with the Preference.xml in which resides under the xml folder. Below is my very simple SettingsActivity.java program together with the preference.xml and SettingsActivity.xml layout
package com.kplau.myapplication5;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import com.kplau.myapplication5.databinding.ActivitySettingsBinding;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivitySettingsBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_settings);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_terms_conditions) {
            // Launch the SettingsActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TermsConditions.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

And the SettingsFragment.java
package com.kplau.myapplication5;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        // Customize preferences here if needed
    }
}

The SettingsActiivity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <!-- Container for Preferences -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
    

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>

And the xml/Preferences.xml file
<!-- res/xml/preferences.xml -->
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="General Settings">
        <!-- Add your preferences here -->
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="enable_notifications"
            android:title="Enable Notifications"
            android:summary="Receive notifications for updates"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <!-- Add more preference categories if needed -->
</PreferenceScreen>


In the Android Design layout, i did see the Bottom Navigaton Menu, but when i run it, it does not show on the both simulator and actual mobile phone device.

